# How do we dynamically read a schema from a schema file in scala

Tags: scala

In my scala code,I am giving the schema directly in case class,

Is it possible to read the schema from  a schema file  and apply that schema in case class?

```
case class Txn(custId: Int,txnDt: String, spentAmt:Long)

object simple {

 def main(args:Array[String])={

                                ...
                               }
}
```

I am looking for something like below

```
 case class Txn('$txn_schema')
```

Let's say I have a schema file named project.schema

**project.schema**

```
txn_schema=custId: Int,txnDt: String, spentAmt:Long
cust_schema=cust:Long,name:string
```

Comment: How would this even work when accessing `Txn` parameters, if you don't know their name? If you really need to, use a `Map[String, Any]` that maps parameter names to values.

Comment: I was not looking for  actual data for each parameter, I am just looking for that schema layout alone. let's assume if the  no . of parameters are 100 , then the case class declaration at top occupies more space, hence I was looking for reading the schema layout alone from a schema file

Comment: You could either write macro to generate classes in compile time or generate them before compilation with sbt plugin or something like this. Google protobuf for example.